# iAd error "Ad inventory unavailable"

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I'm adding iAd to my app. Now, in simulator, it works well but when I load it on a device (v4.1) the *ADBannerViewDelegate* calls *bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:* with this description on the *error.userInfo*

```
{
    ADInternalErrorCode = 3;
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Ad inventory unavailable";
}
```

I think my iAd Network setup is correct. Have I to add an ad by myself or iAd Network automatically sends test ads as in simulator?

EDIT: I think it was a latency problem of the iAd Network server that dispatches the ads. I suppose that when the network had ads for my app it began to work fine.

Comment: If the solution is in the comments, why not accept it?

Comment: Because the solution are on my comments. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a latency problem of the iAd Network server that dispatches the ads. I suppose that when the network had ads for my app it began to work fine.

Comment: This was my problem as well. After having waited (goggled the problem and wound up here) for about 30 seconds the test-ad suddenly appeared.

Answer (score 5):

if you running with a development certificate you will only get test ads even when running on a device. From the [iAd Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/TestingiAdApplications/TestingiAdApplications.html):

> While you are developing your
>   application, iAd Network sends test
>   advertisements to your application. To
>   assist you in validating your
>   implementation, the iAd Network
>   occasionally returns errors to test
>   your error handling code. You can also
>   test your error handling support by
>   turning your device’s wireless
>   capability off.

So you should see the test Ad on the device but you will never see a real live ad.

Comment: Thanks, kharrison, I already read it. The problem is that I don't see nor real or test ads, nothing, it always returns that error :(

Comment: did you enable your app for iAds with iTunes Connect? I assume you did if you are seeing tests ads in the simulator. Also does your device have network connectivity?

Comment: It was all ok, kharrison. Maybe I missed something on ITC but know it works without aditional programming or configuration. I supose it was a "lag" issue. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Removing app from device and rebuilding solved it in my case.

Comment: This answer is a lot better than the selected one which is not an actual answer but a wish of the user that thinks that things will get better in the future.:-)

Answer (score 2):

After this did not work for me, deleting the app from the device and doing a clean build did.

Answer (score 2):

Just an additional update, running ad testing on my IPAD I got this error suddently, after banging my head (as others have done) for a while I noticed the time on the IPAD was 8 mins out, both were set on auto but still 8 mins difference, set the IPAD clock manually and error went away!.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

According to the ADBannerView class reference of Apple's documantation [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

```
enum {
ADErrorUnknown = 0,
ADErrorServerFailure = 1,
ADErrorLoadingThrottled = 2,
ADErrorInventoryUnavailable = 3,
ADErrorConfigurationError = 4,
ADErrorBannerVisibleWithoutContent = 5,
ADErrorApplicationInactive = 6
};
typedef NSUInteger ADError;

//ADErrorInventoryUnavailable
//Indicates that no advertisements are currently available to download.
//Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
//Declared in ADBannerView.h.
```

Therefore it is an exception caused by the server side of the iAd; not the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

For the last 5 days I've been having the same issue. I was getting a valid response before that and the bannerViewDidLoadAd delegate method was been called. Maybe there is something on apple's side? I didn't find anything that implies that, but it's my guess